# What does "my (%input)" mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, cgi

I just started on a new job, which includes maintaining some Perl code. Unfortunately, I am a newbie in Perl but I did my best to search for all answers through books and online, and couldn't find any. My question is straightforward actually - what does the following lines means?

```
my(%input);
my(%query);
```

I understand that "my (List of variables)" from different sources is to declare a list of variables, as well as the % sign being a hash, but does not find any reference for `my (%xxx)`.

I went through the CGI script that contains this but did not find any reference to the above two lines, i.e. as `%input` or `$input`. No module etc is also being specified. Can I safely delete these two lines?

I really ran out of ideas so will appreciate any advice.

Comment: `I understand that "my (List of variables)" from different sources is to declare a list of variables, as well as the % sign being a hash` - You've answered your own question.

Comment: No, I didn't. I am merely sharing what I understand. I just do not understand why I can declare hashes as variables.

Comment: Hashes *are* variables, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types

Comment: Typo on my part above. Rather, it should be " I just do not understand why I can declare hashes as _values_." A straightfoward question - Is "my(%input)" the same as "my %input"?

Comment: "I just do not understand why I can declare hashes as values." I don't understand what that means. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the script have `use strict; use warnings;`? 
Anyways, you can initialize more than one variable with parens. For example, you could have `my ($in, $out);` instead of `my $in; my $out;`. This is often done to group variables by something. In this case you could omit the parens. Maybe the author grouped some other variables and wanted to indicate here that those two hashes are not similar to any other group of variables?

If your two variables never show up again, feel free to delete the lines. And if you `use strict;` (what you really, really should), you will be notified in case they actually do get used later.

P.s. Your hashes could also show up with array sigils as hash slices, for example like `@input{$key1, $key2}`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices

Comment: Thanks DeVadder. I understand about initializing more than one variables in parens such as my ($in, $out, undef). What I still don't understand about putting hashes within the parens. e.g. What is my (%input) declaring?

Comment: @jefferson The same as `my %input;` It just declares a hash with the name `input`. That hash is initially empty. The parens are from the `my` function and just *may* be omitted if used with only one argument.

Comment: Thanks for the short and sweet answers.

Answer (score 3):

The [perldoc web site](http://perldoc.perl.org/) is the best place to get information about Perl. Random Googling for Perl information can lead you to some right dodgy places.

The `my` function is defined in the [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) manual page. Full details are [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html).

Details of how the various types of Perl variables are declared and used can be found in the [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) manual page.

Note that your hash `%input` could be referred to as `%input`, `$input{key}` or `@input{list of keys}`.

> Can I safely delete these two lines?

What happens if you try that? Or, rather than deleting them, perhaps just comment them out at first. The Perl comment character is `#`.

**Update:** To attempt to explain what I think is the real source of confusion here.

As it says in [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html), `my` takes a list of variables. So you see things like this:

```
my ($foo, @bar, %baz);
```

Which declares three variables, a scalar, an array and a hash.

Of course, a single item list is still a list. So you can declare a single variable.

```
my ($foo);
```

In this case, the parentheses are optional. You get the same effect from

```
my $foo;
```

But if you're declaring more than one variable, the parentheses are mandatory;

```
my $foo, @bar, %baz; # This doesn't work
```

So, in the original question we have:

```
my(%input);
my(%query);
```

If it was my code, I'd write that as

```
my (%input, %query);
```

But either of them are exactly the same as

```
my %input;
my %query ;
```

It doesn't matter which variation you choose.

It should also be noted that the call to `my` is often used on the left hand side of an assignment operator, which will then initialise the variables with the values from the right hand side of the operator.

```
my ($scalar, $another_scalar, $a_third_scalar) = (1, 10, 100);
```

Here, both sets of parentheses are necessary. In both cases they are used to construct lists.

To explicitly answer another question from a comment here:

> What is `my (%input)` declaring?

It is declaring a hash called `%input`. The hash is initially empty.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I had already went through the perldoc site, many Perl books and online search but still couldn't find the answer. I can understand my %hash = ("Quarter", 25, "Dime", 10, "Nickle", 5) for example but to have the %hash within the parens such as my (%hash) really confused me. It wouldn't be so confusing if it's my %hash ();, even though this may be wrong as well.

Comment: Well, like I said, random Googling for Perl stuff can't really be recommended. Which is why I made [Perl Search](http://search.perlhacks.com/).

Comment: Perl Search or the perldocs doesn't help me in this at all, which is why I ended up asking here. I re-ran through the links provided here, even though I had already read them before, but NONE of them clear my doubts. Though I appreciate everyone's time, I am hopeful of hearing some quality answers, instead of just links or anything about Google.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if the expanded version is any more help.

Comment: Thanks a zillion for the answers. It's crystal clear to me now.